# Redmine | is there a way to change issuse status form "On Hold" to any other status?

Tags: redmine

I've got one issue in my project which is in "On Hold" status.
Status field is not editable when updating the issue.
Is there a way to change this status to any other form the application?

Redmine v.2.3.1 (account with admin privileges)

Thanks in advance,
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your workflow definitions, you can manage valid state transitions there. In your case, you should be able to change the state of your issue in the move dialog, at least.